# Create matrix for coordinates in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have like a function with a 2D coordinate Parameter like

```
function(a,b)
```

or

```
function([a,b])
```

which returns 1 or 0. (btw. I can easily adjust the parameters of that function)

Now I want to let the function calculate for every possible coordinate between 0 and 100 with 0.1 steps (as example) and output a matrix, so that I can display this matrix as bw image.

My question is how to create some matrix to let the function work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `arrayfun`:

```
[A B]=ndgrid(0:0.1:100,0:0.1:100);
C=arrayfun(@fun, A, B);
```